# Mathematica complex numbers separation

Tags: complex, algebraic-manipulation

It seems like Mathematica cannot separate the expression

```
x / (z + I*y)
```

into a pure real and imaginary part with the `Re[]` and `Im[]` functions.
What is the correct way to get the separated parts?

Comment: Use `ComplexExpand` to tell Mathematica that variables `x`, `y`, and `z` are reals. Therefore, to get the imaginary part of the `expr`, `ComplexExpand[Im[expr]]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`ComplexExpand`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ComplexExpand.html).

Assuming that `x`, `y` and `z` are all reals:

```
ComplexExpand[Im[x/(z + I*y)]]
(* -((x y)/(y^2 + z^2)) *)
```

Assuming that `x` is complex, the rest are real:

```
ComplexExpand[Im[x/(z + I*y)], {x}]
(* (z Im[x])/(y^2 + z^2) - (y Re[x])/(y^2 + z^2) *)
```

Answer (score 0):

See the documentation for `Im`:

> Im[expr] is left unevaluated if expr is not a numeric quantity.

http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Im.html